# Cannot install DynamoDB logstash plugin in Ubuntu

Tags: rubygems, bundler, logstash, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to install "logstash-input-dynamodb" plugin in Ubuntu 14.0.3 server. I'm following http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.DynamoDBLogstash.html tutorial and I've below mentioned tools available in the environment.

OS - Ubuntu server 14.0.3

ruby version- 1.9.3p484

jruby version- jruby 1.5.6

gem version - 1.8.23

When I'm trying to run "bundle install" it throws below mentioned error  message and terminates

---

```
[!] There was an error parsing Gemfile: There was a NoMethodError while loading logstash-input-dynamodb.gemspec:
undefined method metadata=' for #<Gem::Specification name=logstash-input-dynamodb version=1.0.0> from /home/ubuntu/logstash-input-dynamodb/logstash-input-dynamodb.gemspec:19:inblock in
'
. Bundler cannot continue.

# from /home/ubuntu/logstash-input-dynamodb/Gemfile:2
# -------------------------------------------
# source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gemspec
    # -------------------------------------------
```

---

Can some one please share your thoughts on this?

Comment: Given below is on line 19 :- # Special flag to let us know this is actually a logstash plugin
  s.metadata = { "logstash_plugin" => "true", "logstash_group" => "input" }

Comment: If the s.metadata definition is joined up to the comment line, then the given error "undefined method metadata" might make sense.

Comment: They are two separate lines. s.metadata= is not commented.

Comment: Are you using the ruby binary from within jruby (i.e. .../.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.19/bin/ruby)?  That seems to work for me.

Comment: @Raymond  I've both Ruby and Jruby installed in this environment. It seems it doesn't use Jruby. Could you please let me know how to use Jruby instead?

Comment: Check your path to see where it's getting ruby from:
$ which ruby
You can modify your path to include the JRuby bin directory before the normal Ruby bin directory